# Adding form action in html in laravel

Tags: html, forms, url, laravel, action

I am unable to pass url in views html form action tag.

```
<form method="post" action="??what to write here??" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

I want to set it's action to `WelcomeController@log_in` function in `WelcomeController` file in controllers.

Here are my routes:

```
Route::get('/','WelcomeController@home');
Route::post('/', array('as' => 'log_in', 'uses' => 'WelcomeController@log_in'));
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');
```

After submitting it keeps the same url

```
http://localhost:8000/
```

And the main error line

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
```

After that there is `1/1 TokenMismatchException in compiled.php line 2440:`

Answer (score 41):

You can use the `action()` helper to generate an URL to your route:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ action('WelcomeController@log_in') }}" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Note that the Laravel 5 default installation already comes with views and controllers for the whole authentication process. Just go to `/home` on a fresh install and you should get redirected to a login page.

Also make sure to read the [Authentication section in the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication)

---

The error you're getting now (`TokenMismatchException`) is because Laravel has [CSRF protection out of the box](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#csrf-protection)

To make use of it (and make the error go away) add a hidden field to your form:

```
<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
```

Alternatively you can also disable CSRF protection by removing `'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken'` from the `$middleware` array in `app/Http/Kernel.php`

Comment: home page started appearing but after clicking the submit button it does not go to that page

Comment: <?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

//Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');
Route::get('/','WelcomeController@home');
Route::post('/', array('as' => 'log_in', 'uses' => 'WelcomeController@log_in'));

Comment: //Route::post('/dashboad', array('as' => 'dashboard', 'uses' => 'WelcomeController@dashboard'));

//Route::get('/logout', array('as' => 'logout', 'uses' => 'WelcomeController@logout'));



//Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@log_in');

Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');

//Route::controllers(['auth' => 'Auth\AuthController','password' => 'Auth\PasswordController']);

Comment: here is the routes.php file in two parts

Comment: You can *edit* your question. Please do that and add the code properly formatted

Comment: please check the answer I posted, I could nt find the question edit option

Comment: Right below the tags there are a few links, one is *edit*. I know edited it in for you. Please delete your "answer"

Comment: And those routes look okay. What do you see after submitting?

Answer (score 20):

**Laravel 5.8**

Step 1: Go to the path `routes/api.php` add:

```
Route::post('welcome/login', 'WelcomeController@login')->name('welcome.login');
```

Step2:  Go to the path file view

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('welcome.login') }}">
</form>
```

Result html

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/api/welcome/login">

<form>
```

Comment: <form method="POST" action="http://localhost/api/welcome/login"> this one is bad practice ... because when you upload the project to the server you need to change the URL with reference to domain name

Answer (score 10):

if you want to call controller from form action that time used following code:

```
<form action="{{ action('SchoolController@getSchool') }}"  >
```

Here `SchoolController` is a controller name and `getSchool` is a method name, you must use `get` or `post` before method name which should be same as in form tag.

Answer (score 9):

1) In Laravel 5 , form helper is removed .You need to first install laravel collective .

Refer link:  https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'log_in')) !!}
```

OR

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => '/')) !!}
```

2) For laravel 4, form helper is already there

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/')) }}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `action="{{ action('WelcomeController@log_in') }}"`

however TokenMismatchException means that you are missing a CSRF token in your form.

You can add this by using `<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

Comment: This answer is essentially the same as the accepted and most voted answer... with less detail. It would be better to upvote that answer than add in your own

Answer (score 7):

**For Laravel 2020. Ok, an example:**

```
<form class="modal-content animate" action="{{ url('login_kun')  }}" method="post">
  @csrf   // !!! attention - this string is a must 
....
 </form>
```

And then in web.php:

```
Route::post("/login_kun", "LoginController@login");
```

And one more in new created LoginController:

```
 public function login(Request $request){
    dd($request->all());
}
```

and you are done my friend.

Comment: This URL helped me in Laravel-8 version - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes

Answer (score 6):

**In Laravel 8:**

*Step 1: In the blade file:*

```
<form action="{{ route('authLogin')  }}" method="post">
  @csrf
  ....
</form>
```

*Step 2: And then in web.php:*

```
use App\Http\Controllers\UsersController;

Route::post('login-user', [UsersController::class, 'login'])->name('authLogin');
```

*Step 3: And in the UsersController:*

```
public function login(Request $request){
    dd($request->all());
}
```

Happy to share. Thanks to ask this question.

** For more information, please see https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes

Answer (score 4):

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => "WelcomeController@log_in")) }}
...
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: Anyone with a little bit of coding knowledge can understand.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set a name to your Routes.
Like this:

```
    Route::get('/','WelcomeController@home')->name('welcome.home');
    Route::post('/', array('as' => 'log_in', 'uses' => 'WelcomeController@log_in'))->name('welcome.log_in');
    Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home.index');
```

I just put name on Routes that need this. In my case, to call from tag form at blade template.
Like this:

```
<form action="{{ route('home.index') }}" >
```

Or, You can do this:

```
<form action="/" >
```

Answer (score 3):

Form Post Action :

```
<form method="post" action="{{url('login')}}" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Change your Route :
In Routes -> Web.php

```
Route::post('login','WelcomeController@log_in');
```

Comment: In my Lumen installation the `action()` function mentioned by many here returned an error, but the `url()` function worked.

Answer (score 2):

The following should work.

```
{{  Form::open( array('url' => action('WelcomeController@log_in'), 'files'=>true,'method'=>'post') )  }}

...
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to store a post in my application, so I created a controller of posts (PostsController) with the resources included:

`php artisan make:controller PostsController --resource`

The controller was created with all the methods needed to do a CRUD app, then I added the following code to the `web.php` in the **routes** folder :

`Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');`

I solved the **form action** problem by doing this:

1. I checked my routing list by doing `php artisan route:list`
2. I searched for the route name of the **store method** in the result table in the terminal and I found it under the **name** of `posts.store`
3. I added this to the **action attribute** of my form: `action="{{route('posts.store')}}"` instead of `action="??what to write here??"`

Answer (score 0):

Your form is also missing **`'{{csrf_field()}}'`**