# Laravel issue with route and HTML form action

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I'm having some trouble with my form, on submit I get the error 'Whoops, looks like something went wrong.'.

I'm using Laravel 4.2, my routes look like this:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('index');
});

Route::post('/', array('as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'HomeController@login'));
```

And my form looks like this:

```
<form action="{{ action('HomeController@login') }}" method="post">
     <input class="signUpField-index" id="signUpEmail-index" type="text" placeholder="Email Address (required, but never shown) *" name="email" />
     <input class="signUpField-index" id="signUpPassword-index" type="password" placeholder="Password *" name="password" />
     <input id="signUpSubmit-index" type="submit" value="Sign Up" />
     <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
</form>
```

And my controller looks like this:

```
<?php

class HomeController extends BaseController {

public function showIndex()
{
    return View::make('index');
}

public function login() {
    //return var_dump(_POST);
    return View::make('index');
}
}
```

I think it might be the action that is incorrect but I am not too sure, I've tried to look at other examples and tutorials like here: [Adding form action in html in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28984369/adding-form-action-in-html-in-laravel), but they have not helped.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not `action`,its `url`.
Use:

```
<form url="your action" method="post">

</form>
```

But if you want to stay on a same page,use Ajax for submit.