# How to use action with Laravel 5.7 and Laravel Collective

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting this error every time I want to use Action() in forms

```
Action App\Http\Controllers\RentBikeController@store not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\BikeRental\resources\views\Pages\bike.blade.php)
```

My controller code is:

```
<?php
     namespace App\Http\Controllers;

     use Illuminate\Http\Request;
     use App\Http\Requests;

     class RentBikeController extends Controller
     {
     /**
      * Display a listing of the resource.
      *
      * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
      */
     public function index()
     {
         //
     }

     /**
      * Show the form for creating a new resource.
      *
      * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
      */
     public function create()
     {
         //
     }

     /**
      * Store a newly created resource in storage.
      *
      * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
      * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
      */
     public function store(Request $request)
     {


         echo 'chuj';
     }

     /**
      * Display the specified resource.
      *
      * @param  int  $id
      * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
      */
     public function show($id)
     {
         //
     }

     /**
      * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
      *
      * @param  int  $id
      * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
      */
     public function edit($id)
     {
         //
     }

     /**
      * Update the specified resource in storage.
      *
      * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
      * @param  int  $id
      * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
      */
     public function update(Request $request, $id)
     {
         //
     }

     /**
      * Remove the specified resource from storage.
      *
      * @param  int  $id
      * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
      */
     public function destroy($id)
     {
         //
     }
   }
```

View Code

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'RentBikeController@store']) !!} 
     <div class="form-group">
         {{Form::label('title', 'Title')}}
         {{Form::text('title', '', ['class' => 'form-conrol', 'placeholder'=> 'Title'])}}
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         {{Form::label('body', 'Body')}}
         {{Form::textarea('body', '', ['class' => 'form-conrol', 'placeholder'=> 'text'])}}
     </div>
    {{Form::submit('submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

I know I can use something like this `Route::post('/bike/1','BikeController@store')` but I really don't want. 
I also tried to use this solution [Adding form action in html in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28984369/adding-form-action-in-html-in-laravel) but then I get another errors

Comment: actually it was my mistake when copying. Code edited

Comment: I believe you'll need to add that to your `web.php` route file for Laravel to "see" it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to routes folder ***web.php***

```
Route::resource('bikes', 'RentBikeController');
```

And change your `Form::open` to this:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'route' => ['bikes.store'], 'autocomplete' =>
                            'off', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}
```

Comment: Can you give a sample for action feature of laravel collective?